# Evaluate FHIR Expression in Java against an object

Tags: java, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I'm very new to the FHIR standard and I could use some help figuring out how to evaluate a ruleExpression against an object.

Here is my object:

```
@ResourceDef(name = "TestObj", profile = "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/TestObj")
@Data
public class TestObj extends DomainResource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Child(name = "numMarbles")
    @Extension(url = "http://hl7.org/fhir/CustomExtension/numMarbles", definedLocally = true, isModifier = false)
    @Description(shortDefinition = "The number of marbles I have in my pocket")
    private IntegerType numMarbles;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run a rule evaluation on it. For example:

> String ruleExp = "%numMarbles > 3"

In order to try options.. I've setup the following integration test:

```
@Test
void doRuleEval() throws Exception {
    TestObj t = new TestObj();
    t.setNumMarbles(4);
    
    String ruleExp = "%numMarbles > '3'";
    
    FhirPathR4 path = new FhirPathR4(fhirContext);
    
    // ?????
    Object something = path.evaluate(t, ruleExp, null);

    // Line above always fails: "unknown fixed constant %numMarbles"
    
    log.info("something: " + something.toString());
}
```

I've scoured the FHIR documentation and can't find java examples for how to evaluate dynamic rules against FHIR models. In the Javascript library we used the "compile" method but I can't find the equivalent Java method.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

The "evaluate" method is not documented - it takes in an "IBase" object which is any FHIR object from what I can tell, and returns some sort of list... who knows.

The FhirPathR4 object also contains a "parse" method that returns nothing and is also un-documented.

Thanks for any help or tips to point me in the right direction for evaluating a "ruleExpression" against an object's fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would go onto the HAPI FHIR Google group as ask about the evaluate method there.
https://groups.google.com/g/hapi-fhir?pli=1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to answer the question, I would recommend taking a look at [ask].